# How can I make Azure WebRole as NTP Server?

Tags: azure, udp, ntp

**Do you know the way how to set azure webrole as NTP Server ?**

I'd like to synchronize my computer's time with my azure webrole's time exactly instead of 'time.windows.com' or other ntp servers.

Because I need to synchronize my computer's time as accurate as possible with my webrole's time, and I'm thinking of the only way is setting my azure webrole as my local computer's NTP Server.

I tried to command (like 'w32/tm ...~~~' and etc..) on my azure webrole to make it as NTP Server, and it didn't work, although it worked on my different computer which is in my office.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure roles (Web, Worker etc.) do not support hosting of UDP endpoints currently so I'm not sure what you are attempting to do is feasible. Windows Azure Virtual Machines (Preview) can host UDP Endpoints so this might be one workaround (albeit expensive).

Check out this great blog post for a detailed explanation of Azure VM's and NTP Server details.

How frequently is the clock on my Windows Azure VM synchronized? : http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2011/08/25/azure-faq-how-frequently-is-the-clock-on-my-windows-azure-vm-synchronized/

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to know why you want to synchronize with the web/worker roles directly instead of with time.windows.com. The web/worker role VMs are synchronized with time.windows.com by default anyway. Also, Windows Azure does support UDP protocol with their latest June 2012 update.

Comment: Hey Avilay Parekh, can you provide a link to UDP support for Cloud Services plz, I can't seem to find anything, I know VM's (IAAS) has this capability, wasn't aware Cloud Services did? (must have slipped through the cracks!)